# How to be removed from googleplusdirectory.net listing?

Tags: google-plus

I found my personal info at this url http://googleplusdirectory.net.

I tried to send an email to info@googleplusdirectory.net ,as it is suggested by their contact link, but this is not a valid address.

Did anyone ever find a way to prevent this site from crawling personal information from google plus account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much you can do if it simply scraped the publicly available information from Google+.

All you can really do is hope the owners of that site (which is not a Google site) are honest and remove your information and change your G+ profile so less information is shared with the world to prevent this sort of thing in the future.

One outside chance might be to get Google's lawyers to go after the site. I don't know what standing they'd have to do that, though,  or if they'd even bother with something that small.